# What is the regex used to fetch particular string?

Tags: c#, regex

this is my input string.

```
33 FA PAX 001-7243691655/ETAA/USD908.61/19APR13/DCA1S211E/49881               
   134/S2-5                                                                
029 AF/FA 001-7243691655/ETAA/USD908.61/19APR13/DCA1S211E/                 
    49881134/AA2010 S 14MAY SFOORD/AA 054 S 14MAY ORDMAN/AA                
    055 O 11JUN MANORD/AA1661 O 11JUN ORDSFO/BENNION/MEGHAN                
    R(CHD)                                                                 
029 RF-MZ CR-DCA1S211E 49881134 SU 1983MZ/RO-67ECDAB1 DCA1S2               
    10W 49592222 19APR0550Z
```

Here I want to fetch the string according to starting digit.Digit's are :-

```
 33 

029 

029
```

Comment: I do not understand your problem, can you please expand your question?

Comment: @dotTutorials:- Actually I need regex for split string according to starting number. o/P:- 33 FA PAX 001-7243691655/ETAA/USD908.61/19APR13/DCA1S211E/49881               
   134/S2-5

Comment: this done for all three number those I mentioned above.

Comment: -1. Write code for me is not a good question. If you can't write regular expression yourself you'd better not use it as reading regular expression is generally harder than writing. Basic `String.Split` may be safer choice.

Comment: I tried string.split with regex but it's not work properly. I am using these regex  ^\s*(\d{1,3}\s)|^\s*(\d{1,3}\/\d{3}\s).

Comment: So it can be any digit..right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex i hope this will help you

```
(?m)^\s*\d{2,3}|\/\d{3}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this regex

```
^\s*(\d+).*$
```

The above regex would select a line if starts with 0 to many space(\s*) followed by 1 to many digits

`^` marks the beginning of string and `$` marks the end of string(**Note**:`^`,`$` are required else it would match anywhere inbetween the string)

`\d` matches a single digit.`\d+` would match 1 to many digits

`(A|B)` would match A OR B

`.` matches any character except newline if multiline(**default**) option is used

`*` is a quantifier which matches previous char 0 to many times

---

Your code would be

```
List<String> lst=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```

Now you have list(`lst`) of required lines

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is use the `MultiLine` option

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match m = regex.Match(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am always using RegexPal for testing my Regex code.

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to recieve the first 'numbers' of each line. Additionally the numbers may vary from 2-3 characters long?

Try the following regex:

> ^\d{2,3}

The ^ matches a linebreak or the first character
The \d specifices that you are looking for a number
{2,3} specifies that the number you are looking for may be between two and three letters long.